# Inside fragment ViewPager takes long time to load child fragment

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

I have problem that it takes long time to load data and show only when i scroll the view pager. Several time i already used asynctask but not work. After changing tab, i called same fragment any one help me??

[Here, is first time loaded data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0hcV.png)

[After changing tab call same fragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4l6Kc.png)

**Here is my Adapter for ViewPager**

```
public class AdapterCategoryViewPager extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
Context context;
private List<Fragment> fragmentList;
private List<Type> typeList;

public AdapterCategoryViewPager(FragmentManager fm, Context context, List<Fragment> fragmentList, List<Type> typeList) {
    super(fm);
    this.context = context;
    this.fragmentList = fragmentList;
    this.typeList = typeList;
}


@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return fragmentList.get(position);
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return typeList.get(position).getType().toString();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return fragmentList.size();
}
}
```

**Here is my Fragment for category this function i call on async task**

```
private void setData(View v)
{
    addWomenCategory();
    ll_list.removeView(v);
    gridView.removeView(v);
    gridView.setMode(PullToRefreshBase.Mode.PULL_FROM_END);
    adapterCategory=new AdapterCategory(v.getContext(),categoryArrayList,height,width);
    gridView.setAdapter(adapterCategory);
    g=(GridView) gridView.getRefreshableView();
    g.setHorizontalSpacing(h7);
    g.setVerticalSpacing(h7);
   // g.setEnabled(false);

    gridView.setOnRefreshListener(new PullToRefreshBase.OnRefreshListener<GridView>() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh(final PullToRefreshBase<GridView> refreshView) {
            gridView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    refreshView.getLoadingLayoutProxy().setRefreshingLabel("Loding Data...");
                    refreshView.getLoadingLayoutProxy().setReleaseLabel("Refresh complete");
                    addWomenCategory();
                    adapterCategory.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    gridView.setRefreshing(false);
                    gridView.onRefreshComplete();

                }
            },2000);
        }
    });
}
```

**Here is my HomeFragment which actually add fragments category in array list this function i also called in asynctask**

```
private void setData(View v)
{
    addType();
    pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
    adapterType=new AdapterType(typeArrayList,v.getContext(),height,width);
    fragmentList.add(new FragmentListCategory());
    fragmentList.add(new FragmentMenListCategory());
    fragmentList.add(new FragmentKidListCategory());
    fragmentList.add(new FragmentListCategory());
    fragmentList.add(new FragmentMenListCategory());
    fragmentList.add(new FragmentKidListCategory());

    pager.setAdapter(new AdapterCategoryViewPager(getFragmentManager(),v.getContext(),fragmentList,typeArrayList));

   tabs.setViewPager(pager);
    setUpTabStrip(v);


}
```

Comment: Are the images stored locally or you are getting them from internet?

Comment: image stored in drawable folder

Comment: Is it a single image or different images according to size ?

Comment: single image @Vidya Sagar

Comment: I have faced the same problem. Android automatically try to resize the image according to screen resolution which sometimes cause delay in populating the view...Use online resources and generate images one for each resolution like hdpi,mdpi, xhdpi,xxhdpi and xxxhdpi. Use them and your problem could be solved

Comment: http://www.appance.com/tag/asset-resizer/

Comment: Let me know if your problem is solved or not...

Comment: its not working @Vidya Sagar

Comment: Post your code.....It will give a better idea

Comment: What is your problem exactly?

Comment: The thing is, you are doing bad practice on storing the fragment in list and set it into your viewpager adapter.

Comment: It loads data late first time or every time?

Comment: first time it run correct after changing tab it not show any data@Anshul Tyagi

Answer (score 1):

I have used universal imageloader library to display image and i was initialized its object every time in adapter to solve this issue i initialize that configuration object only once in whole application in main activity's onCreate() method

Comment: Yeah. That's the right way to configure your UIL in your singleton application class.

Comment: Consider initializing it on onCreateView method

Answer (score 0):

As addWomenCategeory() being an asynchronous task, the code in the main thread doesn't wait for the result.
Consider moving the code

```
adapterCategory.notifyDataSetChanged(); gridView.setRefreshing(false); gridView.onRefreshComplete();
```

to addWomencategory() method, where you recieve result from your back-end